# Trying to conditional render css to on alternating items in an array with useState in React with MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks, conditional-statements, use-state

I have an object of arrays that I'm mapping over called `featuredProj`, and on alternate items, I want the CSS to conditionally render as not to repeat so much code. Using `useState` in the `handleSide` function I get the error `too many rerenders`. How can I solve this, or is there a better solution to rendering jsx while mapping over an array of objects.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  title: {
    textAlign: (side) => (side ? "right" : "left"),
  },
}));

const FeaturedProjects = () => {
  const [side, setSide] = useState(true);
  const classes = useStyles(side);

  const handleSide = (project, index) => {
    if (index === 0 || index % 2 === 0) {

// I tried setSide(false), setSide(prev => !prev)
        
      return (
        <Grid Container key={index}>
              <Typography className={classes.title}>{project.title}</Typography>
        </Grid>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <Grid Container key={index}>
              <Typography className={classes.title}>{project.title}</Typography>
        </Grid>
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      {featuredProj.map((proj, ind) => (
        <Reveal duration="2000" effect="fadeInUp">
          {handleSide(proj, ind)}
        </Reveal>
      ))}
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Hey @HoangDinh, you're returning the same value inside your `if` and `else` condition.

Comment: Ah sorry @bertdida I was taking out code for posting this question to make it easier to read, I took out too much. Basically the else value is supposed to return jsx elements in a different order as well as have different css values.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `setState()` inside render method. `setState()` will trigger a re-rendering which calls render method again which leads to another `setState()`.. you get the idea.

If you want it to work, you need to create separate component with the `side` props and pass it as an argument to your style hook.

```
const FeaturedProjects = () => {
  const classes = useStyles(side);

  return (
    <Container>
      {featuredProj.map((proj, ind) => (
        <FeaturedProjectItem
          key={index}
          project={proj}
          side={index === 0 || index % 2 === 0}
        />
      ))}
    </Container>
  );
};

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  title: {
    textAlign: (side) => (side ? "right" : "left"),
  },
});
const FeaturedProjectItem = ({ side, project }) => {
  const classes = useStyles(side);

  return (
    <Reveal duration="2000" effect="fadeInUp">
      <Grid Container>
        <Typography className={classes.title}>{project.title}</Typography>
      </Grid>
    </Reveal>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for replying @NearHuscarl, I was trying to avoid writing multiple classes to have less lines of code.

Comment: I've updated my answer regarding your concern @HoangDinh

Comment: that looks like a really good solution, also hits my goal of making it more modular! I'll try implementing this, thank you!